# Center an image inside a div without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to center an image inside a div without absolute positioning, because the picture overflows onto any other div that might be on the page. For example, I have a div above the container div which will contain buttons, but the image is overflowing onto it. Is there any way to center the image without absolute positioning?

Some more information - I am using Electron. The image is actually a base64 encoded image which was taken from a canvas (`canvas.toDataURL()`) and sent to the main process using IPC. After this, the window's location is changed to another html file, and when the new page is fully loaded, a request is sent via IPC to receive the image again. The image is then inserted into an img tag on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ipcRenderer.send('display-snap');
    ipcRenderer.on('reply-snap', (event, arg) => {
        $("#snapshot").attr("src", arg);
        //$("#snapshot").css('background-image', 'url(' + arg + ') no-repeat center center');
    });
});
```

Setting the src works, but the commented out code doesn't work (I was trying to use a div instead of an img, but the background image property of the div is never set).

[Here's a JSFiddle of what I am trying to do](https://jsfiddle.net/0e91fod6/1/). The image should be centered in the content div and *only* the content div, without overlapping the menu div. The image should be centered horizontally *and* vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The image should be centered [**per deleted comment** *apparently both vertically and horizontally*] in the content div and only the content div, without overlapping the menu div.

Flexbox can do that

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu {
    height: 64px;
    background-color: red;
}

#container {
  height:100%;
  }

#content {
  display: flex;
  height:calc(100% - 64px);
  justify-content: center; /* center horizontal */
  align-items: center; /* center vertical */
  overflow: hidden;
  background:#c0ffee
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
    
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <img id="snapshot" src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/200" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/window.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the content div fill the remaining space on the web page, so that the image will always be centered even when resizing?

Comment: Yep, check the demo out at full page size.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an inline element then you can use `text-align: center.`

Here is an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9mvtw46/)